# Search box supports multiple search with comma separated vales

Tags: telerik

in Search box which allows to give one id for search. I want to make this search box that allows me to give multiple comma separated  inputs like id1,id2,id3 if I click search then 3 records should pop up. 
I am using telerikUI for the first time... is there any component that supports this functionality? I know I can achieve this in c# using split function. Looking how I can do in telerik.ui

Answer (score 0):

We can add parameter which takes multiple values for this purpose.   Here I have demonstrated it with a parameter(Organization)
[Add multivalued Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9awqr.png)
[Add datasource to get list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdcLF.png)
[Add display member and value member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JISUh.png)
[Configure datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ2Gv.png)